# Making PHP file upload secure with htaccess

Tags: php, security, file, .htaccess, upload

I am working on a task to make the PHP file upload secure and my client wants to follow the guideline mention on the website http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/upload-forms-threat.htm

We are able to follow all the guidelines mentioned on this site accept from htaccess rule. They have mention to do following.

```
Define a .htaccess file that will only allow access to files with allowed extensions.
Do not place the .htaccess file in the same directory where the uploaded files will be stored. It should be placed in the parent directory.
A typical .htaccess which allows only gif, jpg, jpeg and png files should include the following (adapt it for your own need). This will also prevent double extension attacks.

deny from all
<Files ~ "^\w+\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
order deny,allow
allow from all
</Files>
If possible, upload the files in a directory outside the server root.
Prevent overwriting of existing files (to prevent the .htaccess overwrite attack).
Create a list of accepted mime-types (map extensions from these mime types).
Generate a random file name and add the previously generated extension.
Don’t rely on client-side validation only, since it is not enough. Ideally one should have both server-side and client-side validation implemented.
```

So that no other files than gif, jpg and png will be executed. But they don't want the htaccess to be in the folder where we upload images as that folder has permissions and htaccess can be overwritten. So they tell to keep the file at root level.

I want to know that if we keep the file at root level and allow only image types to execute then how my php scripts will be executed? When I add this htaccess at root level, off course my php scripts don't work and return permission error. Struggling to get this work out.

Can you help me with get this working or any other effective way to do this security check. We don't want to keep security loopholes on system.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 5):

Code can be encoded into image files, so you should disable the PHP engine for this directories:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

Or, if you can't set that in an .htaccess file, then you can do it in your httpd.conf or vhost conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # ...

    <Directory /path/to/webroot/path/to/upload/folder>
        deny from all
        <Files ~ "^\w+\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
            order deny,allow
            allow from all
        </Files>  
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            php_flag engine off
        </IfModule>      
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks mmmshuddup for the solution, I have access to .htaccess file. Just want to know that if its possible to restrict it on folder. I mean, I can have .htaccess in public_html folder and I want to block scripts in public_html/user_uploaded_files folder. So the php_flag engine off code should block it in only user_uploaded_files folder. Many thanks.

Comment: Make a _new_ .htaccess file for that the public_html/user_uploaded_files directory such that its path would be: `public_html/user_uploaded_files/.htaccess` and put the `php_flag engine off` in there.

Comment: That is the point. I actually thought the same before but many people recommended that we should not keep the .htaccess file in forlder with write permissions as it can be overwritten by hacker. I want to keep htaccess at root level and block the content in user_uploaded_files folder. Is that doable? thanks for your replies.

Comment: Sorry yeah that's right. I had forgotten because by the time you sent me those last messages nothing was fresh in my mind anymore. Well those are your two choices (unless some guru has a better idea): either put the .htaccess file in that folder or change it in the apache conf.

Comment: Yes, I think I will take apache conf route. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Anytime! Let me know if you need anything else. Cheers!